# Katalon Studio calling closure in teardown method

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I am working on a test case in Katalon Studio that fills out a prompt to add n rows to a table, and wish to, as teardown step, try to delete those rows. I have written the test deletion logic to a test case that I call from inside a closure. I then call that closure as a first step in the teardown. However, When I run the test, it silently fails to actually teardown. I get an error message like this

```
Error occurred when try to run method 'tearDown' (Root cause: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException - org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1529594455360.deleteRowsAdded() is applicable for argument types: () values: [])
```

and my closure and teardown method is defined as follows:

```
def deleteRowsAdded = {

    while (driver.findElements(By.xpath(dataRowsSelector)).size() > initialRowCount) {
        WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('DeleteStore'), [('shouldLogout') : true, ('shouldCloseBrowser') : true, ('loginAndCompanySelect') : true
                                                         , ('index') : initialRowCount], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
    }
}

@TearDown
def tearDown() {
    deleteRowsAdded()

    if (shouldLogout) {
        WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Sign In/li_Sign Out'))
    }

    if (shouldCloseBrowser) {
        WebUI.closeBrowser()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `findTestCase('DeleteStore')` test case?